# how to count unique values after groupby ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe **df**

```
ID  from   to
A    0x    0c
A    0x    0f
A    0f    0n
B    0f    0c
B    0c    0f
C    0k    0j
C    0j    0k
C    0k    0a
```

First I want to group by `id` and only keep groups if the number of unique values from `from` and `to` combined is less than 3.

so the desired df will be

```
B    0f    0c
B    0c    0f
C    0k    0j
C    0j    0k
C    0k    0a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a groupby [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) with a lambda function that confirms the number of unique values in the `from` and `to` columns is less than or equal to 3? You can use [`DataFrame.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) as a hacky solution to put all of the values in a dataframe into a single Series to use [`Series.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) with:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataframe here
df = pd.read_clipboard()

out = df.groupby("ID").filter(lambda x: x[["from", "to"]].stack().nunique() <= 3)
```

out:

```
  ID from  to
3  B   0f  0c
4  B   0c  0f
5  C   0k  0j
6  C   0j  0k
7  C   0k  0a
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to ask, after we use nunique after stacking, does it in fact count the pair of values in the resulting series with multi index?

Comment: It counts the unique values across the entire subframe. So it would be equivalent to putting every value in one big list and then counting the uniques.